# Zed: How to search across all files within a workspace?

Tags: ide, key-bindings

How does one search for occurances across all files in the Zed editor?

In vscode, I can click on the search icon in the toolbar. Is there an equivilent in Zed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** you can open up the Project Search pane using <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

---

Within the Command Palette (opened using <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>), the command is called `Pane: Deploy Search`, this opens up a new "Project Search" pane in the editor.

[image: Image of the Zed IDE showing the Project Search pan open in the editor]

The key binding for this option is <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, which can be configured by defining your own [custom key bindings](https://zed.dev/docs/key-bindings#custom-key-bindings) in the `keymap.json` file.